# Why some packages in flutter works with java while some work with kotlin

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart, flutter-packages

I have faced this issue while building my app.
lets consider two cases

1. `audioplayers 0.20.1`

when i include java support in my flutter project `audioplayers 0.20.1` package works well with it . but when i include kotlin support in my project it gives me errors while building the project. It works well with java but doesn't works with kotlin.

2. `fluttertoast 8.0.8`

when i include kotlin support in my flutter project `fluttertoast 8.0.8` package works well with it . but when i include java support in my project it gives me errors while building the project. It works well with kotlin but doesn't works with java.

why this contradictory cases is occurring here

and suppose i want to include both the `fluttertoast 8.0.8` and `audioplayers 0.20.1` in one project so which support should i include java or kotlin. my project will fail here in either case

Can someone plz explain me this?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I get kotlin sdk not found error but it is already installed in my system